# Discrete-time Markov chain properties

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

A Markov chain in discrete time is irreducible, has state space $\{0,1,\dots\}$
and starts at $1$. It is both a branching process and a martingale.
Determine the probability of hitting $0$.

Comment: what did you try in solving this problem?

Comment: Where did you get the problem? Why does it interest you? What do you know about Markov chains, about irreducibility, about branching processes, about martingales?

Comment: Nice question (the answer is $1$). It is a pity that this user is mishandling the site to such an extent...

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that this is a birth-and-death reversible MC (rate of inflow=rate of outflow for each state), and the transition probabilities are $p,q,r$ (to go up one state/down one state, remain in the same state) with $p+q+r=1$ and boundary value $h_{0,0}=1$ we can get the following equation:
$$
h_{1,0}=qh_{0,0,}+rh_{1,0}+ph_{2,0}\\
p h_{1,0}=qh_{2,0}
$$
The second equation come from the reversibility property (detailed balance equation). Solving these, we get:
$$
h_{1,0}=\frac{q^2}{p^2-q^2+pq}
$$

Comment: Your question was to determine the probability of 'hitting 0' without providing any specific details. This is this probability under some specific assumptions on the MC

Comment: Offtopic. The hypotheses made in this answer contradict the assumption that the process is *both a branching process and a martingale*.